# Regex & Javascript - Double Vertical Bar

Tags: javascript, regex, logic

I am trying to replace any "||" in a string with "∨" with the following code:

```
var s = f.replace(new RegExp("||", "g"), "∨");
```

However, the following occurs when f = "A→(A→A)"

```
f = "∨A∨→∨(∨A∨→∨A∨)∨
```

I have tried escaping in as many possible ways as I can think of, but I think it is because it is the double vertical bar structure that's causing me the issue.

Comment: If your using a string literal form of the RegEx constructor,  you will want this -> `.replace(new RegExp("\\|\\|", "gu"), "v")`    basically the `\|` is to escape the `|`,    `\\` the double is required as `\` requires an escape inside strings.  Alternatively use the not string version as @linasmnew  has shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` represents `OR`, so your regex `||` is matching empty strings `''` `(''|''|'')`. You should use `\|\|` instead.

```
|A|→|(|A|→|A|)|
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ <= matches empty string '' between chars
∨A∨→∨(∨A∨→∨A∨)∨
```

```js
var wrong = 'A→(A→A)'.replace(new RegExp(/||/, "g"), 'v')
var right = 'A||A||A'.replace(new RegExp(/\|\|/, "g"), 'v')

console.log(right, wrong)
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace all `||` with a `v`, try this:

```
var s = f.replace(/\|\|/g, "∨");
```

*Given input:* `f = "A||→(A||→A)";`

*It will output:* `A∨→(A∨→A)`